# cakephp - getting the correct path in a javascript file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, path

I'm trying to use a $.post() jquery call in a javascript file which I have in my webroot/js folder.

The javascript file gets called in a number of places and I'm struggling to figure out what the correct path to use is.

I'm using the following at the moment

```
$.post("../../spanners/deleteSpanner", function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

But obviously using the ../../ won't work in certain parts of the app.

What can I replace ../../ with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the place of your app on your server and how spanners controller's deleteSpanner action is access. Suppose the following:

```
mywebsite.com/spanners/deleteSpanner ===> $.post("/spanners/deleteSpanner"...



mywebsite.com/someApp/spanners/deleteSpanner ===> $.post("/someApp/spanners/deleteSpanner"...
```

To prove this concept for you, checkout this demo: http://jsbin.com/APejeQa/1 in-which the src of the jsbin logo website could be accessed from any page level by just starting its path by `/`

```
<img src="/images/jsbin_static.png" alt="jsbin logo" />
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks but I'm not understanding you properly I don't think. Also the link which you sent keeps timing out for me. I tried removing the ../'s and just start with a / but that didn't work

Comment: So, this prove that your issue is not a path issue. It may be something else in your entire code. As a final test, try to access your action via full URL. i.e `http://mysite.com/spanners/deleteSpanner` from your web browser first and see if there any errors? if there is no any errors, supply it as path in $.post().

Answer (score 0):

in your view file type this above:

```
echo $javascript->link('spanners/deletespanners');
```

Comment: Hey there, I'm not trying to include the javascript file. I'm trying to reference a controller->action in the javascript file. So I need to know how to get a reference to the webroot in a javascript file in the webroot/js folder